# Inserting class as STL map key value

Tags: c++

I want to to add a simple class consisting of two integer values (like x and y position) as key value if map, I guess that to do that i need to overload < operator, but for some reason i can't get it right. Here's exactly what i want to squeeze in as key:

```
struct position {
 int x;
 int y;
};
```

Comment: An easy way to overload that is to wrap the values into `std::pair`s and compare those. It already does the strict weak ordering part.

Comment: what mapping do you want your map to define? what is key and what value?

Comment: key should be a position in x and y. As value i want another int (so basically i want to assign a number to a certain position).

Comment: Is position the key or the value?

Comment: a position in x and y: please decide : p

Comment: position is the key. @cf16 can't i put them both in? From other people doing same project i heard that best way to store needed data is map, but i do need both x and y.

Comment: @user2221390 is my solution what you need? you have your position object with int as its key

Comment: well, the int I first intended to be a value will repeat itself (ie positions 0,0 and 1,1 can have same value), so i dont think i can use it as a key in map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual way.

```
bool operator<(position p, position q)
{
    return p.x < q.x || (p.x == q.x && p.y < q.y);
}
```

it gives position a *strict weak ordering* which is what is required by `std::map`. The order itself is a bit arbitrary but that doesn't usually matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems like it's what i've been looking for- the order isn't really important here.

Answer (score 0):

standard way is to `make_pair` and to insert it to your map:

```
map<int,position> ip;
position pos{1,8};
std::pair<int,position> pair=std::make_pair<int,position>(1,pos);
ip.insert(pair);
```